# Attach ActiveStorage blob with a different filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rails-activestorage

I am looking for the most elegant way of attaching/duplicating an `ActiveStorage` **blob** with a different name.

My current best solution is using the IO interface and downloading and re-uploading the file which seems rather inefficient.

```rb
url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url( contract.document )
attachements.push([
  io: open( path_url ),
  filename: "New contract filename"
])
```

I know you can do this, which is only touching the database:

```rb
contract.attach( contract.document.blob )
```

But I need to change the filename.

The *ActiveStorage* documentation seems to be spotty on this subject and I couldn't really find what I was looking for.

Comment: probably symlinks can help to change file name without content like `ln -s old.png new.png` , then just to put new record in sql database with new name

Comment: @itsnikolay Blobs are stored on a remote server.  In this case I am using an S3-like service.

Answer (score 4):

The constraints of Active Storage mean that you definitely will need to duplicate the blob. Within Active Storage, the blob key is indexed uniquely, so it cannot be referenced twice by different filenames.

If your storage service allows you to duplicate the blob efficiently in situ, then the enabling method on the Rails side is [`create_before_direct_upload!`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-c-create_before_direct_upload-21).  Despite the somewhat misleading name, this method is specifically documented to provide a new (but unattached) blob record, in expectation that the content itself will be uploaded outside of the application.  The blob record is then attached in a subsequent operation.

That is how Direct Upload works, and we can hook into the same two-phase mechanism; in this special case, the "upload" will instead be a service-specific duplication.

The means to duplicate in-situ vary according to the storage service, but for example:

- S3's [`CopyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) call,
- The AWS S3 Ruby SDK's [`copy_to`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#copy_to-instance_method) method,
- A Unix file system's [hard link](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-ln).

An illustrative chunk of demonstration code therefore might be:

```rb
def blob_clone(current_blob, **options)
  blob_parameters = { 
    filename: current_blob.filename,
    byte_size: current_blob.byte_size,
    checksum: current_blob.checksum,
    content_type: current_blob.content_type,
    metadata: current_blob.metadata,
    **options
  }

  service = current_blob.service
  new_blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!(**blob_parameters)

  case service.class.name
  when 'ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service'
    bucket = service.bucket
    current_object = bucket.object(current_blob.key)
    current_object.copy_to(bucket.object(new_blob.key))
  when 'ActiveStorage::Service::DiskService'
    current_path = service.path_for(current_blob.key)
    new_path = service.path_for(new_blob.key)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(new_path))
    FileUtils.ln(current_path, new_path)
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "unknown blob storage service #{service.class.name}"
  end

  new_blob
end
```

to be used thus:

```rb
current_blob = mymodel.contract.blob
new_blob = blob_clone(current_blob, filename: 'newfilename.pdf')
new_model.contract.attach(new_blob)
```

although I recommend refactoring this example according to your application structure and preferences.

#### Note on the code

In the illustration above, the `case service.class.name` is rather unlovely, and is only written so to keep the demo code self-contained.  The problem being that Rails doesn't even load the class constant for an unused backend storage service.  If you are not using diverse storage services across environments, then the case-statement may be unnecessary, and if this were fully realised as a gem, or refactored into an initializer, I'd probably finesse it to be monkey-patching/refining the service classes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to point to the same blob but with a different name, maybe you can try to add the needed record in the database.

This is the schema for the active storage attachments table:

```rb
  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end
```

You should be able to add a new record with almost the same values and a different name.

Maybe something like:

```rb
my_object.my_attachments.create(blob_id: my_object.document_blob.id, name: 'new name')
```

Comment: The `name` in `active_storage_attachments` doesn't refer to the filename but the name of the attachment you used in: `has_one_attached :avatar` -> `avatar`. Good suggestion though. It was my first thought as well when I looked at that table.

Answer (score 1):

The `StringIO` can convert downloaded blob to `IO` then you can use any name you want.

```
attachements.push([
  io: StringIO.new( contract.document.download ),
  filename: "New contract filename"
])
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveStorage creates two tables `active_storage_blobs` which includes the uploaded files information like (filename) and `active_storage_attachments` which is a join table between a model record and a blob.

```rb
# rails console
=> ActiveStorage::Attachment
(id: integer, name: string, record_type: string, record_id: integer, blob_id: integer, created_at: datetime)
=> ActiveRecord::Blob
(id: integer, key: string, filename: string, content_type: string, metadata: text, byte_size: integer, checksum: string, created_at: datetime)
```

To change the filename of a blob supposing that

`contract` model `has_many_attachments :documents`

```rb
contract_object.documents.first.blob.update(filename: 'new file name')
```

To duplicate a blob you can pass a blob object to [`attach`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Many.html#method-i-attach), then rename the filename